# Fetch data from MYSQL Database using AWS API

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm pretty new to the AWS platform. I want to Fetch data from RDS MYSQL Database to my Python application using API. I couldn't find any relevant tutorial to achieve this task. It will be awesome If you could guide me or send a proper tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I couldn't find any relevant tutorial to achieve this task.

This is because such operation is **not supported**. To connect to your RDS database and get its data you have to use regular mysql tools, such as `mysql` cli, `phpmyadmin` or `mysql workbanch`.

You can only use AWS API for Mysql if you are using [Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html) and its [data api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html).